# Can I make this get and setvalues from many cell script faster or make it better?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I have many values in many cell that have to set it to another sheet.This script use around 10 sec to setvalues.Can I make it faster or make it better?
I have other function that similar to this run at the same time too. So it make process slower than 10 sec to be around 30 sec. Can I use .map and hoe to do it?

```
const wsformPO = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("formPO");
const doc_Type_V = wsformPO.getRange("H22").getDisplayValue();
const wsPOV = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetID1").getSheetByName("data_pov");
const wsPON = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetID1").getSheetByName("data_pon");

const item1_Data_1_V = [[wsformPO.getRange("H23").getDisplayValue(),
                       wsformPO.getRange("H24").getDisplayValue(),
                       wsformPO.getRange("C27:E27").getDisplayValue(),
                       wsformPO.getRange("C28").getDisplayValue(),
                       "1",
                       wsformPO.getRange("C33:D33").getDisplayValue(),
                       wsformPO.getRange("F33").getDisplayValue(),
                       "USE"]]

const po_data_1_V = [[wsformPO.getRange("C29").getDisplayValue(),
                      wsformPO.getRange("H27").getDisplayValue(),
                      wsformPO.getRange("H28").getDisplayValue(),
                      wsformPO.getRange("J27").getDisplayValue(),
                      wsformPO.getRange("J28").getDisplayValue()]]

const item1_Data_2_V = [[wsformPO.getRange("H33").getDisplayValue(),
                        wsformPO.getRange("I33").getDisplayValue(),
                        wsformPO.getRange("J33").getDisplayValue()]]

const po_data_2_V = [[wsformPO.getRange("J69").getDisplayValue(),
                      wsformPO.getRange("J70").getDisplayValue(),
                      wsformPO.getRange("J71").getDisplayValue(),
                      wsformPO.getRange("J73").getDisplayValue(),
                      wsformPO.getRange("J74").getDisplayValue(),
                      wsformPO.getRange("J75").getDisplayValue(),
                      wsformPO.getRange("J76").getDisplayValue(),
                      wsformPO.getRange("J77").getDisplayValue()]]

const item2_Data_1_V = [[wsformPO.getRange("H23").getDisplayValue(),
                       wsformPO.getRange("H24").getDisplayValue(),
                       wsformPO.getRange("C27:E27").getDisplayValue(),
                       wsformPO.getRange("C28").getDisplayValue(),
                       "2",
                       wsformPO.getRange("C45:D45").getDisplayValue(),
                       wsformPO.getRange("F45").getDisplayValue(),
                       "USE"]]

const item2_Data_2_V = [[wsformPO.getRange("H45").getDisplayValue(),
                        wsformPO.getRange("I45").getDisplayValue(),
                        wsformPO.getRange("J45").getDisplayValue()]]

const item3_Data_1_V = [[wsformPO.getRange("H23").getDisplayValue(),
                       wsformPO.getRange("H24").getDisplayValue(),
                       wsformPO.getRange("C27:E27").getDisplayValue(),
                       wsformPO.getRange("C28").getDisplayValue(),
                       "3",
                       wsformPO.getRange("C57:D57").getDisplayValue(),
                       wsformPO.getRange("F57").getDisplayValue(),
                       "USE"]]

const item3_Data_2_V = [[wsformPO.getRange("H57").getDisplayValue(),
                        wsformPO.getRange("I57").getDisplayValue(),
                        wsformPO.getRange("J57").getDisplayValue()]]


function savetoPOVN(){

  if(doc_Type_V === "V"){

  wsPOV.getRange(wsPOV.getLastRow()+1,2,1,8).setValues(item1_Data_1_V);
  wsPOV.getRange(wsPOV.getLastRow(),11,1,5).setValues(po_data_1_V);
  wsPOV.getRange(wsPOV.getLastRow(),17,1,3).setValues(item1_Data_2_V);
  wsPOV.getRange(wsPOV.getLastRow(),20,1,8).setValues(po_data_2_V);
  wsPOV.getRange(wsPOV.getLastRow(),60,1,4).setValues(note_V);
  
    if(item2_amount_V != ""){
      wsPOV.getRange(wsPOV.getLastRow()+1,2,1,8).setValues(item2_Data_1_V);
      wsPOV.getRange(wsPOV.getLastRow(),11,1,5).setValues(po_data_1_V);
      wsPOV.getRange(wsPOV.getLastRow(),17,1,3).setValues(item2_Data_2_V);}

    if(item3_amount_V != ""){
      wsPOV.getRange(wsPOV.getLastRow()+1,2,1,8).setValues(item3_Data_1_V);
      wsPOV.getRange(wsPOV.getLastRow(),11,1,5).setValues(po_data_1_V);
      wsPOV.getRange(wsPOV.getLastRow(),17,1,3).setValues(item3_Data_2_V);

  }
  var range = wsPOV.getRange(6,2,wsPOV.getLastRow()-1,63);
  range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true});}

  if(doc_Type_V === "N"){

  wsPON.getRange(wsPON.getLastRow()+1,2,1,8).setValues(item1_Data_1_V);
  wsPON.getRange(wsPON.getLastRow(),11,1,5).setValues(po_data_1_V);
  wsPON.getRange(wsPON.getLastRow(),17,1,3).setValues(item1_Data_2_V);
  wsPON.getRange(wsPON.getLastRow(),20,1,8).setValues(po_data_2_V);
  wsPON.getRange(wsPON.getLastRow(),60,1,4).setValues(note_V);

    if(item2_amount_V != ""){
      wsPON.getRange(wsPON.getLastRow()+1,2,1,8).setValues(item2_Data_1_V);
      wsPON.getRange(wsPON.getLastRow(),11,1,5).setValues(po_data_1_V);
      wsPON.getRange(wsPON.getLastRow(),17,1,3).setValues(item2_Data_2_V);}

    if(item3_amount_V != ""){
      wsPON.getRange(wsPON.getLastRow()+1,2,1,8).setValues(item3_Data_1_V);
      wsPON.getRange(wsPON.getLastRow(),11,1,5).setValues(po_data_1_V);
      wsPON.getRange(wsPON.getLastRow(),17,1,3).setValues(item3_Data_2_V);
      }
    var range = wsPON.getRange(6,2,wsPON.getLastRow()-1,63);
     range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true})
}};
```

Comment: Instead of doing ```.getValues()``` and ```.setValues()``` for many times, use ```.getDataRange().getValues()``` to get all data of the source sheet in one go, than modify the 2D array in javascript to form the output you are looking for, than use one ```.setValues()``` to put everything onto the target sheet.